# On new iPhone, when I call people no one can hear me but I can hear them

Tags: iphone

I got a new iPhone last weekend and have a problem: why can’t people hear me on the other end of the phone when I call them? Any tips on what the cause could be?

Comment: Although it may be a more complex issue, I would try the Voice Memos app to see if the mic works or not.

Comment: This *may* indicate that you are, in fact, a ghost.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming everything is actually OK with your phone then I had same problem.

I read on another post it is an issue with Apple's attempt at noise cancelation when making calls when background noise is present.  It was suggested to disable noise cancellation by enabling hearing aid mode (under General-->Assesibilty).  They only down side is it makes you enable bluetooth and amplifies your handset volume a bit.  I tested it with several people and they all noted how much better they could hear and understand me.

Answer (score 3):

I still had the protective plastic film on my screen to protect it until I get a proper screen protector. Removing this has fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Would do as falconbridge says: "Although it may be a more complex issue, I would try the Voice Memos app to see if the mic works or not."  If your device does not register sound through that app it's likely that your microphone is bad.

- If it's a new phone bought directly from an Apple Store I would take it to them and you will most likely get a new phone if it clearly isn't your fault.
- If you do not get a new phone I suggest calling http://www.iCracked.com or any other local repair store

Answer (score 2):

On the back of the phone is the camera, the flash, and in between is a little pin hole

That pin hole is supposed to receive outside intruding noise, and filters that noise out of the mike where you talk.

Trouble is, your own voice travels up the back of the phone case, and starts to filter your own voice out - people cant hear you.

I filled mine with linseed glazing putty

Comment: Shit that worked i blocked the space between the camera and the flashlight,...

Comment: Why not disable the feature in software? Is there a benefit to physically obstructing the opening?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the microphone has gone. I had this problem when I purchased my IPhone from Carphone Warehouse. I took it back and their [Geek Squad](http://www.geeksquad.co.uk/) repaired it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning the phone off and back on again after about 3 min...Worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after replacing the back housing of an iphone. The noice cancellation was the cause of this. By disabeling this the problem was solved. The new back cover had a whole in the back with no kind of tissue in it.

Answer (score -1):

If they cannot hear you but can hear you on speaker phone than you are most likely in need of a charging port replacement for your iPhone. The bottom mic is located on the same flex cable as the charging port.

Answer (score -3):

Try disabling voice cancellation. Which is under general > accessibility > voice cancellation. This kind of worked for me.

Comment: What does this add that hasn't already been said?